# Catch the backend returned error in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

Hellow All, I'm using the  react redux with typescript. So, When the back end returned the error I wan't it as it's error message return from the back end. In my Api return this error when a failure.

[image]

this the my api call, fucntion 
,

```
   /**
 * @function createSalesContact
 * @export
 * @param {Array<ISalesContact>} salesContact
 * @returns {Promise<ISalesContactListItem[]>}
 */
export function createSalesContact(salesContact: Array<ISalesContact>): Promise<ISalesContactListItem[]> {
    return contactBookApiCalls.createSalesContacts(salesContact);
}
```

Here the my action,

```
/**
 * @function crateSalesContact
 * action of create new sales contact
 * @param {Array<ISalesContact>} salesContact
 * @returns
 */
export const crateSalesContact = (salesContact: Array<ISalesContact>) => {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch, states: () => ISalesContactStoreState) => {
        dispatch(requestAddNewContact());

        createSalesContact(salesContact)
            .then(onSuccess)
            .catch(onError);

        function onSuccess(response: ISalesContactListItem[]) {
            dispatch(addToast("success", { text: "Sales Contact Created successfully" }))
            dispatch(addNewContactSuccess());
            dispatch(togglePage({ page: 'salesContact', action: 'View', 
            editId: response[0].Data.SalesContactId }));

        }

        function onError(error: any) {
            dispatch(addNewContactError(error));
        }
    };
};
```

So I wan't catch "The firstName is required" error. So what are the possible way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find some work-round for this. Here the my solution.

I change my Action error method like this.

```
function onError(response: Response) {
        if (response.status === 500) {
            return response.json() 
                .then((json) => {

                    dispatch(addToast("error", { text: json.Message }));
                    dispatch(recieveSalesContactUpdateError(json.Message));

                    console.log(json.Message)
                });
        } else {
            return response.json();
        }
    }
```